# No bug in console, but javascript won't run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this in order to make a for visisble to enable it again, but somehow, the console won't log anything and I really don't know what the error is.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        $('#wrapper').css({
            "height": "0%",
            "opacity": "1",
            "display": "initial"
        });
        $(".form-container input").removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#wrapper').find('p').first().remove();
    });
});
```

This is the HTML I used;

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-left"style="margin-top: 31%; margin-left: -48.75%;">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" style="width: 200px; outline: none;border-color: #58D998;box-shadow: #58D998;">
            <button type="submit" placeholder="" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me syntax-wise...theres NOTHING when you click on the button? Or perhaps an error saying `$ is not defined`?

Comment: can you show the HTML ? What is the type of `.btn` ?

Comment: Is `.btn` a dynamically created element? Maybe you need some delegation.

Comment: @omri: learn about [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/): No.

Comment: The .btn I use is the Bootstrap default button, I'll include HTML in a second. No, nothing at all happens when clicking .btn..

Comment: try adding and selecting another class that isn't part of bootstrap, like 'eventButton' to make sure nothing else is clearing your handlers.

Comment: You use btn with type="submit" to post a form together with doing js stuff.....omg

Comment: Not true ^ I need to have an email first before scrolling down to a form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a submit button so it will refresh the page, you need to cancel the click event.

```
$('.btn').click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
```

And you should not use removeAttr to removed disabled, use prop()

```
$(".form-container input").prop('disabled',false);
```

---

If you are saying it does not work, I am guessing you need to change how you are listening for the event

```
$(document).on("click", '.btn', function (e) {
```

Comment: Very sorry to say this, but this doens't work either. Thanks for the tip about the removeAttr :), will see if it works when i'm able to test it ;-)

Comment: Love the downvote by random person. Your issue was the fact you were trying to add an event before the button was there or something was wiping away the event.

Comment: Yeah probably, still I think it's a strange situation though, yeah I saw that xD very weird